# Why imported JavaScript file Not Working in Astro?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, astrojs

why js file not working in Astro when I import or add src in Astro file?
ex: `<script src="../scripts/local.js"></script>` or `<script>import '../scripts/local.js'</script>`

I'm working on a local environment and I'm sure I've written my src URl correctly but my functions aren't working. this is my written js code

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("[data-navLink]");
navLinks.forEach((link) => {
  if (link.getAttribute("href") === window.location.pathname) {
    link.setAttribute("aria-current", "page");
    console.log(window.location.pathname);
  }
});
```

Comment: you can only `import` in a `module` `<script>` ... check your browser console for the errors - also, your "code" is a template literal, so, basically a string, that won't do anything

Answer (score 1):

[`<script>` tags are hoisted as `type="module"` by default](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#script-bundling), for your script you need to add a [`is:inline` directive](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#isinline) to opt out of this default and inline your script

This section of this docs: [Scripts and Event Handling](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts), has a bunch of great information on how client side scripts work in Astro

It is also worth noting that you can create active links server side using `Astro.url.pathname` instead of using a client-side script

```
<a aria-current={Astro.url.pathname === '/home' ? 'page' : null}>Home</a>
```